# Return File from ngx-image-cropper to upload - Angular

Tags: angular, image, file, blob, node-modules

I am using [ngx-image-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper) to crop my image. I need to retrieve the cropped image from [ngx-image-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper) to upload. However, I can't retrieve File object through this.

This is the code that I used to trigger when the user crop the image,

```
imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
    this.croppedImage = event.base64;
    this.cropperHeight = event.height;
    this.cropperWidth = event.width;
    this.croppedEvent =event.file;//This is how i tried to get file
}
```

When I am trying to upload the file it has some error. So it is better to provide a way to get file object from ngx-image-cropper

Comment: Can you make a Stackblitz or show the event object?

Comment: Looks like this was removed in the 3.0 release. https://github.com/Mawi137/ngx-image-cropper/pull/314

Comment: There is a way. We can return **base64** of the cropped image. Then we can convert it into blob (base64 to blob) and create File using that blob.

Comment: @nipun-kavishka it is creating a corrupted file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To return the cropped image as a file instead of a base64 string, add the following:

```
import { ImageCroppedEvent, base64ToFile } from 'ngx-image-cropper';

  imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
    // Preview
    this.croppedImage = event.base64;

    const fileToReturn = this.base64ToFile(
      event.base64,
      this.data.imageChangedEvent.target.files[0].name,
    )

    return fileToReturn;
  }


  base64ToFile(data, filename) {

    const arr = data.split(',');
    const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
    const bstr = atob(arr[1]);
    let n = bstr.length;
    let u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }

    return new File([u8arr], filename, { type: mime });
  }
```

Answer (score 27):

The package includes the method `base64ToFile`

```
// Import the method:

import { ImageCroppedEvent, base64ToFile } from 'ngx-image-cropper';

.....
imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
    this.croppedImage = event.base64;
    let File = base64ToFile(this.croppedImage);
}
```

source: https://github.com/Mawi137/ngx-image-cropper/releases/tag/3.0.0

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: How would you hook up a HTML button to call this function?

Comment: this return Blob type object but we need File type can we do that. Or is it same when we pass image to api

Comment: To make it a File instead of Blob you can `file : File = new File([fileBlob], originalFile.name,{lastModified: originalFile.lastModified, type: originalFile.type});`

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. It's quite frustrating, given the fact that in the specs for this library they show that you can specify an output type. But then when you look at the d.ts files there is no overload for .crop() that takes a string argument for `output?: blob | base64`

Comment: This method is increasing the file size.

Answer (score 0):

I solved sending the original file to the function and creating a new File instance on image-cropper **crop( originalFile:** File **)** function:

```js
import { ImageCroppedEvent, base64ToFile } from 'ngx-image-cropper';
...
crop(originalFile): File {
   ...
   ...
   output.base64 = this.cropToBase64(cropCanvas);
   if(originalFile){
     const file = new File([base64ToFile(output.base64)], originalFile.name, {lastModified: originalFile.lastModified, type: originalFile.type});
     return file;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for ^1.5.1 version:

```
imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
    this.croppedImage = event.base64;
    const file_image: File = this.imageChangedEvent.target.files[0]; //The change event from your file input (set to null to reset the cropper)
    const file = new File([event.file], file_image.name, {type: file_image.type});

    console.log("file", file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ImageCroppedEvent, LoadedImage } from 'ngx-image-cropper';

export class YourComponent {
    imageChangedEvent: any = '';
    croppedImage: any = '';
    
    constructor(
      private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) {
    }

    fileChangeEvent(event: any): void {
        this.imageChangedEvent = event;
    }
    imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
      this.croppedImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(event.objectUrl);
      // event.blob can be used to upload the cropped image
    }
    imageLoaded(image: LoadedImage) {
        // show cropper
    }
    cropperReady() {
        // cropper ready
    }
    loadImageFailed() {
        // show message
    }
}
```

source: https://github.com/Mawi137/ngx-image-cropper/releases/tag/7.0.0